# controlling excel through dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, async-await, vba

I am trying to run a stored proc which inserts data into tables. After doing that, I am refreshing the excel that is stored in my local machine(this excel has data connections to the db)
  I am having issues as the refresh is consuming time, after which I want to save the excel - which is getting called early. I want to get control back from excel once the refresh is complete.

Can I read the status of excel through C#?

I have been trying to use async code which blocks the current thread and refreshes the excel in an other thread. The issue with this approach is that the thread is returning immediately(task.iscompleted is returning true) even though the refresh is still running.

How can I avoid this?

Also:

- Can I individually refresh the sheets?
- When the refresh is done, can I pass control back to .NET?

This is the code for refresh task:

```
    private static async Task refreshExcelAsync(Excel.Workbook sampleWorkBook)
    {

        Task t = new Task
        (
            () =>
            {
                sampleWorkBook.RefreshAll();

            }
        );
        t.Start();

        await t;
    }
```

and I am calling this function using:

```
 Task refreshExcelTask = refreshExcelAsync(sampleWorkBook);
 Task t = await Task.WhenAny(refreshExcelTask);
```

after this call I am calling a saveExcel task based on the condition t.IsCompleted

but this condition is always returning true!

Comment: Your code demonstrates that you are already controlling Excel through .NET. So what does: **Also, Is there any way to control excel through .net?** mean exactly?

Comment: I am just doing a refreshAll(), I want to individually refresh the sheets if I can, and after the refresh is done, I want the control back in the dotnet web app which i am not able to get currently.

Comment: As heads up Excel, although things should have changed with the Server Components, can have serious scaling and threading issues running on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the `QueryTables` from the `Worksheets` of the `Workbook`. From there, you can refresh them, passing `false` to disable [background refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197503%28v=office.14%29.aspx). You can also subscribe to the [`AfterRefresh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835922%28v=office.14%29.aspx) event to be notified when a background refresh is completed.